# getting "XAUUSD=X" from yahoo.finance.historicaldata

Tags: yql, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to get data for "XAUUSD=X" between two dates, but always i get result: null. Who knows, what is wrong? My YDN request:

```
SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.historicaldata WHERE symbol= 'XAUUSD=X' and    startDate="2015-01-1" and endDate="2015-08-23"
```